# How to embed Java libraries in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, embed

I have a working RoR application, I want to insert some Java code into it. What is the best option for me ?

Answer (score 3):

Use [JRuby](http://www.jruby.org) as your Ruby VM.